# Elasticsearch: Count how many value in document

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a document that looks like this:

```
{
  "_index": "table_data",
  "_type": "_data",
  "_id": "some_id_here",
  "_score": null,
  "_source": {  
 "Like": [
      "John_ID",
      "John_ID",
      "leanh.pham"
    ],  
    "Comments": [
      "phanthanhthuycic",
      "John_ID",
      "phanthanhthuycic",
      "John_ID",
      "lu.t.anh",
      "John_ID",
      "phaanht",
      "ham.d.hi",
      "Thien1977",
      "John_ID",
      "lu.t.anh",
      "John_ID",
      "John_ID",
      "bui.52"
    ]
  },
  "fields": {
    "date": [
      1491267574000
    ]
  },
}
```

I want to get the number appear of "John_ID" in document. (in this document, John_ID appear 8 times in Like and Comments)
I used this query

```
{
  "_source": [
    "John_ID"
  ],
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "date": {
        "query": 1491267574000
      }
    }
  },
     "aggs" : {
        "types_count" : { "value_count" : { "field" : "Comments.keyword" } }
    }
}
```

But its not give me right answer.
I hope that i can get help from you
I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: What do you get instead?

Comment: value_count will not help here. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-valuecount-aggregation.html

Comment: I have this result : "aggregations": {
    "types_count": {
      "value": 6
    }
  }

Comment: Are you sure Elastic is the best DB for you?..